# need to show date in yyyy/mm/dd format in java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am using `Nebulla DateChooserCombo`. I have used it as `dateChooserFrom.getText();`. It is Producing the result like 7/31/2011 which is in `m/dd/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` format. I need the result in `yyyy/mm/dd` format. For that I have use the code as.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
String s = df.format(dateChooserFrom.getText());
```

But when I run the code it says `Cannot format given Object as a Date` . so please anybody could help me on this. I am using eclipse rcp and java.

Comment: What is the actual exception being thrown. More information required.

Comment: @ brett the actual exceptation is 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
 at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)'

Comment: you say that component produces "mm/dd/yyyy", but your pattern is "yyyy-MM-dd". See the difference? slash versus minus?

Comment: btw, is this your component? http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/datechooser/datechooser.php

Comment: @deadsven  it's ok with any kind of format like "yyyy-mm-dd"or yyyy/mm/dd but i need the yyyy in the front and mm in the middle. yes i am using the same you have written.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DateFormat dffrom = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
DateFormat dfto = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
Date today = dffrom.parse("7/1/2011");
String s = dfto.format(today);
```

Convert the String to Date first.

Comment: @ cularis thanks that works. but some time "M/dd/yyyy" can be also "MM/dd/yyyy" i should probably count the length and implement the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Nebulla DateChooserCombo is but I guess the problem is related to the returning type of the instance method getText. Is is a date? Because you have to pass an instance of java.util.Date to the format method.

Comment: .getText give the result in the string Format.

Comment: So this is the reason because you can't use the format method. I think you could create a date from this text and use the formatter to obtain the other format.

Comment: @ all i didn't find any method that the dateChooserCombo return in date format. can i format the given string value into Date.

Comment: See the docs for SimpleDateFormatter. The class contains also a method for parsing date. You could just create a formatter for converting your input in a date. Then you could use the code you have already written. @cularis just added the code in the next reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Date date = new Date();
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTime(date);
      SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//you can use any format that you want, for example:("yyyy/MM/dd")
      String s = SDF.format(date);
      System.out.print(s);
      }
}
```